# Listar fechas de los 15 de cada mes, lo más sencilla posible

Tags: python, python-3.x, date

Quiero crear una lista de los días 15 del mes desde una fecha XXXX hasta una hoy lo más simple posible, con la menor biblioteca posible.

```
date = []
for year range(start_date, end_date):
    for month in range(1,12):
        date+=f"15-{month}-{year}"
```

Comment: Te acuerdas del método `resample()`??, lo utilice en una respuesta a una de tus preguntas

Comment: Sí, lamentablemente no quiero usar pandas, que tiene demasiadas dependencias @Christian .

Comment: Y Numpy???.....

Comment: ¿Qué son sdate y endate? Edita tu pregunta y pon un ejemplo completo, ejecutable.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Tratando de ser menos:

```
sdate = [2008, 8, 15]
edate = [2018, 9, 15]

calendario = [[n // 12 + 2008, 1 + n % 12, 15] for n in range(sdate[1] - 1, (edate[0] - sdate[0]) * 12 + edate[1] - 1)]

print(calendario)
```

No usa ninguna librería ni función.

El truco está en contar los meses a partir del mes inicial; en este caso, sería la secuencia:

```
n = 1, 2, 3, ...... , 120, 121
```

El valor de `n` se calcula como el número de meses entre ambas fechas.

Cada valor de `n` puede ser reconvertido a `[año, mes, 15]` usando la formula:

```
ano = n // 12 + 2008
mes = 1 + n % 12
```

Teniendo la lista final de `[ano, mes, dia]`, es posible convertirla fácilmente a cualquier otro tipo de objeto.

#### Demo

```
sdate = [2008, 8, 15]
edate = [2018, 9, 15]

calendario = [[n // 12 + 2008, 1 + n % 12, 15] for n in range(sdate[1] - 1, (edate[0] - sdate[0]) * 12 + edate[1] - 1)]

print(calendario)
```

produce:

```
[[2008, 8, 15], [2008, 9, 15], [2008, 10, 15], [2008, 11, 15], [2008, 12, 15], [2009, 1, 15], [2009, 2, 15], [2009, 3, 15], [2009, 4, 15], [2009, 5, 15], [2009, 6, 15], [2009, 7, 15], [2009, 8, 15], [2009, 9, 15], [2009, 10, 15], [2009, 11, 15], [2009, 12, 15], [2010, 1, 15], [2010, 2, 15], [2010, 3, 15], [2010, 4, 15], [2010, 5, 15], [2010, 6, 15], [2010, 7, 15], [2010, 8, 15], [2010, 9, 15], [2010, 10, 15], [2010, 11, 15], [2010, 12, 15], [2011, 1, 15], [2011, 2, 15], [2011, 3, 15], [2011, 4, 15], [2011, 5, 15], [2011, 6, 15], [2011, 7, 15], [2011, 8, 15], [2011, 9, 15], [2011, 10, 15], [2011, 11, 15], [2011, 12, 15], [2012, 1, 15], [2012, 2, 15], [2012, 3, 15], [2012, 4, 15], [2012, 5, 15], [2012, 6, 15], [2012, 7, 15], [2012, 8, 15], [2012, 9, 15], [2012, 10, 15], [2012, 11, 15], [2012, 12, 15], [2013, 1, 15], [2013, 2, 15], [2013, 3, 15], [2013, 4, 15], [2013, 5, 15], [2013, 6, 15], [2013, 7, 15], [2013, 8, 15], [2013, 9, 15], [2013, 10, 15], [2013, 11, 15], [2013, 12, 15], [2014, 1, 15], [2014, 2, 15], [2014, 3, 15], [2014, 4, 15], [2014, 5, 15], [2014, 6, 15], [2014, 7, 15], [2014, 8, 15], [2014, 9, 15], [2014, 10, 15], [2014, 11, 15], [2014, 12, 15], [2015, 1, 15], [2015, 2, 15], [2015, 3, 15], [2015, 4, 15], [2015, 5, 15], [2015, 6, 15], [2015, 7, 15], [2015, 8, 15], [2015, 9, 15], [2015, 10, 15], [2015, 11, 15], [2015, 12, 15], [2016, 1, 15], [2016, 2, 15], [2016, 3, 15], [2016, 4, 15], [2016, 5, 15], [2016, 6, 15], [2016, 7, 15], [2016, 8, 15], [2016, 9, 15], [2016, 10, 15], [2016, 11, 15], [2016, 12, 15], [2017, 1, 15], [2017, 2, 15], [2017, 3, 15], [2017, 4, 15], [2017, 5, 15], [2017, 6, 15], [2017, 7, 15], [2017, 8, 15], [2017, 9, 15], [2017, 10, 15], [2017, 11, 15], [2017, 12, 15], [2018, 1, 15], [2018, 2, 15], [2018, 3, 15], [2018, 4, 15], [2018, 5, 15], [2018, 6, 15], [2018, 7, 15], [2018, 8, 15]]
```

Comment: que solucion tan creativa 5 estrellas!

Answer (score 2):

Un enfoque bastante seguro, es usar las rutinas de `datetime`, calcular la diferencia en meses entre una fecha y otra e iterar esa cantidad de meses para generar cada fecha.

Si tienes las fechas como cadenas, en primer lugar habrá que convertirlas en un objeto `datetime`:

```
from datetime import datetime
from dateutil.relativedelta import relativedelta

sdate = datetime.strptime("16-01-2020", "%d-%m-%Y")
endate = datetime.strptime("16-08-2021", "%d-%m-%Y")
```

---

Para calcular la diferencia de meses voy a tomar prestada [esta](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4040338/6836377) rutina

```
def diff_month(d1, d2):
    return (d1.year - d2.year) * 12 + d1.month - d2.month
```

---

Ahora solo resta iterar, con un enfoque clásico:

```
date_list = []
start = sdate.replace(day=15)
for m in range(diff_month(endate, sdate)):
  date_list.append(start + relativedelta(months=m))
```

---

En primer lugar con `sdate.replace(day=15)` convertimos la fecha inicial, al día 15 y luego simplemente iteramos de a un mes y vamos sumando este a la fecha de inicio mediante `relativedelta(months=m)`

O como una comprensión de listas:

```
[sdate.replace(day=15) + relativedelta(months=m) for m in range(diff_month(endate, sdate))]
```

---

Encapsulado en una función:

```
def get_list_of_days(sdate, endate, nday=15):

  def diff_month(d1, d2):
      return (d1.year - d2.year) * 12 + d1.month - d2.month

  return([sdate.replace(day=nday) + relativedelta(months=m) for m in range(diff_month(endate, sdate))])

import pprint
pprint.pprint(get_list_of_days(sdate, endate, 31))

[datetime.datetime(2020, 1, 15, 0, 0),
 datetime.datetime(2020, 2, 15, 0, 0),
 datetime.datetime(2020, 3, 15, 0, 0),
 datetime.datetime(2020, 4, 15, 0, 0),
 datetime.datetime(2020, 5, 15, 0, 0),
 datetime.datetime(2020, 6, 15, 0, 0),
 datetime.datetime(2020, 7, 15, 0, 0),
 datetime.datetime(2020, 8, 15, 0, 0),
 datetime.datetime(2020, 9, 15, 0, 0),
 datetime.datetime(2020, 10, 15, 0, 0),
 datetime.datetime(2020, 11, 15, 0, 0),
 datetime.datetime(2020, 12, 15, 0, 0),
 datetime.datetime(2021, 1, 15, 0, 0),
 datetime.datetime(2021, 2, 15, 0, 0),
 datetime.datetime(2021, 3, 15, 0, 0),
 datetime.datetime(2021, 4, 15, 0, 0),
 datetime.datetime(2021, 5, 15, 0, 0),
 datetime.datetime(2021, 6, 15, 0, 0),
 datetime.datetime(2021, 7, 15, 0, 0)]
```

Answer (score 1):

OK.
Solo usando librerías estándar, uno podría construirlo así:

```
from datetime import date
from dateutil.relativedelta import relativedelta

# fecha start (s) y end (e)
sdate = date(2008, 8, 15)
edate = date(2018, 9, 15)

# calcular los meses de diferencia entre las dos fechas
delta = (edate.year - sdate.year) * 12 + (edate.month - sdate.month)

# generar la lista (incluye fecha de inicio, se puede cambiar a delta + 1 para excluirla.
for i in range(delta):
    day = sdate + relativedelta(months=+i)
    print(day.strftime("%d-%m-%Y"))
```

Dependiendo de cómo esperes que el usuario introduzca las fechas, quizá tengas que editar la fecha de inicio para asegurar que el día es 15, avanzando 1 mes si el día es mayor que 15 (sino añadirías un 15 fuera de tu rango). La fecha final no hace falta ajustarla. Esto se puede conseguir con:

```
sdate = if sdate.day < 15 sdate.replace(day=15) else sdate.replace(day=15, month=sdate.month + 1)
```